# Tree of Data with each node having a different view on display in IOS

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

this is my first post here in stackoverflow. Well..i'm developing e app for iOS that have a binary tree as the model and i'm wondering how can i associate each node with a particular view in display without transgreding the Model-View-Controller design pattern. What i need is some kind of list associating the particular node with it's corresponde nodeView, so that the controller could determines what nodeView to generate based on what node is passed to it.

Is it clear what i'm trying to do? My english sucks.....sorry for that.

Thanks.